# Error when using @Override

Tags: java, codenameone

At the moment of compiling code for mobile app trial, I have an error with `@Override`.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your actual code to the question using the edit function. Images of code are not helpful, as they cannot be searched. Please also add the specific error message to your question. Like this, finding your problem is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `OutputStream` class from `java.io`. Once you do that the method signature would match the one from the base class and override will work.

Notice that the IDE does that for you if you click the lightbulb in that line as you place the cursor on the word `OutputStream` or if you type <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For completeness just add this below the `package` statement and above the first `class` statement:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
```